# Is there a cross-browser, backwards compatible way to code a background gradient?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I've been looking for a solution to background gradients that work in modern browsers and versions of IE down to 7. If someone has a best practice that works, I would appreciate the method as I keep running into solutions that break on a certain browser or version. It should atleast work in IE7-9, Firefox, Safari, Opera, and Chrome.

Comment: Why not just use a 1 pixel wide n pixel tall image for the background that has your gradient and just duplicate it across the x-axis.  It's old-school but it works.

Comment: @Miguel-F you want a wider image than that.  Some browsers have really poor performance when it comes to repeating very narrow images (flickering, sluggish scrolling).  A safe bet is to use an image that's a minimum of roughly 20px or more wide/tall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As other have said, CSS3 is compatible with FF, Chrome etc.

For IE9, you can use their official [CSS Gradient Background Maker](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/graphics/cssgradientbackgroundmaker/default.html), which will generate an inline SVG image, supported also by most of modern browsers (although it give some issues on Safari).

For IE8, you can use

```
-ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#FFFFFF, endColorstr=#000000, GradientType=1);
```

[Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms530752%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

For IE 5.5 - 7:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr=#FFFFFF, endColorStr=#FFFFFF, GradientType=1);
```

[Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532997%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

`startColorStr` and `endColorStr` are pretty self-explanatory. [GradientType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532887%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is `1` for horizontal and `0` for vertical. There's no such thing as radial nor diagonal gradients before IE9.

I **strongly** suggest you not to use an htc solutions (like css3pie) as they give a lot of side effects.

It's not really easy to implement, but if you need a polyfill there's [cssSandpaper](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2010/03/09/cross-browser-css-transforms-even-in-ie/).

Answer (score 4):

This is a quite complete gradient generator 
  [colorzilla](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)

Anyway for now there isn't a clear standard in css. We hope it will arrive asap !

If you would like to see some gradient even in Explorer 6-8 using a CSS3-like approach (for ex. `linear-gradient(#EEFF99, #66EE33)`, and without using Explorer proprietary `filter`) you can try Css PIE. I used it extensively, it's an amazing piece of software based on HTML Component (.htc), expecially good for buttons, but in my experience has some problem when your page rely on many ajax effects, particularly if you redim the size of the frame/page, because not always the buttons/gradients are updated. (anyway CSS Pie is used even in important sites)

[Css PIE](http://css3pie.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Use [this tool](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) to generate your gradient

Answer (score 1):

Old browsers (< IE7) don't have support to css gradient properties. You can use css3 to make gradient backgrounds and then set a solid color to old browsers.

Comment: There are tools available that provide CSS gradients to legacy IE.

Comment: Renan: True. They don't support CSS3 gradients... but they do support filters. And they have gradient support built in.

Answer (score 1):

No ie7, but this is a good start

```
         background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(150,150,150,0.2) 1%, rgba(80,80,50,0.5) 52%, rgba(20,20,20,0.8) 100%); 
         background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(1%,rgba(150,150,150,0.2)), color-stop(52%,rgba(80,80,50,0.5)), color-stop(100%,rgba(20,20,20,0.8))); 
         background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(150,150,150,0.2) 1%,rgba(80,80,50,0.5) 52%, rgba(20,20,20,0.8) 100%); 
         background: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(150,150,150,0.2) 1%,rgba(80,80,50,0.5) 52%, rgba(20,20,20,0.8) 100%); 
         background: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(150,150,150,0.2) 1%,rgba(80,80,50,0.5) 52%, rgba(20,20,20,0.8) 100%); 
         background: linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(150,150,150,0.2) 1%,rgba(80,80,50,0.5) 52%, rgba(20,20,20,0.8) 100%); 

         /* FF3.6+ */ 
         /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
         /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */ 
         /* Opera 11.10+ */
         /* IE10+ */ 
         /* W3C */
```

Comment: The ie7 part. Look at the other answers for more info.

Comment: AFAIK this particular code doesn't work in IE7. And I'm telling this at the start. You can use filters, but to my understanding It's a horrible hack and I don't use them.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is not related to HTML or CSS. This is a another way that if you know basics of creating gradient images using [MS Paint](http://www.instructables.com/id/Gradients-in-MIcrosoft-Paint/) or [GIMP](http://graphicssoft.about.com/od/gimptutorials/ss/Gradient-Editor.htm) then this technique will work for all type of browsers.