# IE9 background-size for gradient

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, gradient, linear-gradients

Is there a way to use `background-size` for `IE9` for `gradients`? Because in my case, adding `background-size` to `CSS` doesn't have any effect.

[UPDATED]

Sample code:

```
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ccc', endColorstr='#ddd')";
background-size: 2px 100%;
```

In that case, background-size doesn't work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12643956/1577396 check this link

Comment: You are using CSS for gradient or background image?

Comment: IE-9 Supports backgrounds-size http://caniuse.com/#search=background-size

Comment: @Dipaks he is using gradients

Comment: what exactly you are asking background-size or gradient for IE9

Comment: working background-size with background gradient

Comment: [Microsoft Official site for background-image gradients](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/graphics/cssgradientbackgroundmaker/default.html)

Comment: @Mr_Green I can't see using background-size in link you provided

Comment: use that without giving Filters, `background-size` property will work (only in IE9)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`background-size` doesn't work in `IE9` for gradients. Only for images. That's why a solution is using `SVG`.

I found one solution in some website, and little bit change it to support `RGBA` (`SASS`)
Works fine even for IE9 (except webkit's):

```
@mixin svg-linear-gradient($angle, $color1, $color1Alpha, $offset1, $color2, $color2Alpha, $offset2:100, $color3:null, $color3Alpha: 1, $offset3:100, $color4:null, $color4Alpha: 1, $offset4:100, $color5:null, $color5Alpha:1, $offset5:100){
    $angle_webkit:'left top, left bottom';
    $angle_svg:'%20x2%3d%220%25%22%20y2%3d%22100%25%22';
    $color-stop1_svg:'%3cstop%20style%3d%22stop%2dcolor%3argba('#{red($color1)}'%2C'#{green($color1)}'%2C'#{blue($color1)}'%2C'#{$color1Alpha}')%22%20offset%3d%22'#{$offset1}'%25%22%2f%3e';
    $color-stop2_svg:'%3cstop%20style%3d%22stop%2dcolor%3argba('#{red($color2)}'%2C'#{green($color2)}'%2C'#{blue($color2)}'%2C'#{$color2Alpha}')%22%20offset%3d%22'#{$offset2}'%25%22%2f%3e';
    $color-stop3_svg:'';
    $color-stop4_svg:'';
    $color-stop5_svg:'';
    @if $angle == right{
         $angle_svg:'%20x2%3d%22100%25%22';
     }
    @if $angle == bottom{
         $angle_svg:'%20x2%3d%220%22%20y1%3d%22100%25%22';
     }
    @if $angle == left{
         $angle_svg:'';
     }
    @if $color3 != null {
         $color-stop3_svg:'%3cstop%20style%3d%22stop%2dcolor%3argba('#{red($color3)}'%2C'#{green($color3)}'%2C'#{blue($color3)}'%2C'#{$color3Alpha}')%22%20offset%3d%22'#{$offset3}'%25%22%2f%3e';
     }
    @if $color4 != null {
         $color-stop4_svg:'%3cstop%20style%3d%22stop%2dcolor%3argba('#{red($color4)}'%2C'#{green($color4)}'%2C'#{blue($color4)}'%2C'#{$color4Alpha}')%22%20offset%3d%22'#{$offset4}'%25%22%2f%3e';
     }
    @if $color5 != null {
         $color-stop5_svg:'%3cstop%20style%3d%22stop%2dcolor%3argba('#{red($color5)}'%2C'#{green($color5)}'%2C'#{blue($color5)}'%2C'#{$color5Alpha}')%22%20offset%3d%22'#{$offset5}'%25%22%2f%3e';
     }

    background: url('data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg%20xmlns%3d%22http%3a%2f%2fwww%2ew3%2eorg%2f2000%2fsvg%22%20width%3d%22100%25%22%20height%3d%22100%25%22%3e%3cdefs%3e%3clinearGradient%20id%3d%22G%22#{$angle_svg}%3e#{$color-stop1_svg}#{$color-stop2_svg}#{$color-stop3_svg}#{$color-stop4_svg}#{$color-stop5_svg}%3c%2flinearGradient%3e%3c%2fdefs%3e%3crect%20width%3d%22100%25%22%20height%3d%22100%25%22%20fill%3d%22url%28%23G%29%22%2f%3e%3c%2fsvg%3e');
}
```

And how to use it:

```
@include svg-linear-gradient(top, $first, $firstAlpha, 0, $second, $secondAlpha, 100);
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what exactly you want but below link will help you (size and gradient both work fine in any version of IE)

http://css3pie.com/